# Simple wipe animation for image view

Tags: objective-c

I've scoured the internet and I cannot seem to find any help on this. I want to have an image perform a wipe animation. By that I mean I would like the image itself to fade in from the left to right (not move from left to right, but fade, like reveal itself. I hope that's not a terrible description) I've found material on how to transition the image with a wipe, but it's outdated and I don't want to transition the image, I want to straight up fade it in. If anybody could help me on this I would be incredible grateful. Thank you so much, let me know if I can help clarify anything!

Comment: Could you show your code? By fade, you mean playing with its alpha? What went wrong with solutions you found?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that came to my mind is to have a separate UIImageView, with image something like this: http://www.creativecow.net/articles/ahearn_luke/creating_clouds/images/gradient.jpg  (but transparent-to-white).

So - once You want to fade out Your image, You add as a subview a new UIImageView, which has frame like 3 times the width of the original image You want to hide. Once You add it as a subview, visually nothing would change, as the beginning of the hovering UIImageView would be transparent, But then You start animate frame (origin.x) of the hovering UIImageView so that it would be moved to the left side. While this happens, bottom ImageView will be gradually hidden from one side. After animation ends, You remove/hide both UIImageViews.

Not the best solution, but - if You are stuck, and still want the effect... Atleast some option.. Good luck!